# как поменять расположение окон браузера selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

хотел сделать программу, которая открывает 10 отдельных окон хрома на определенной странице atomichub, но проблема в том, что я хотел бы, чтобы окна были +- 400 на 300 пикселей и расположенными в разных областях экрана, чтобы было удобнее, как мне сделать так, чтобы эти 10 окон были в разных координатах?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.set_window_size(400, 300)


driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver1.get("http://www.google.com")
driver1.set_window_size(400, 300)
```

это начальная заготовка

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать методы `get_window_postiton` и `set_window_position`. Точкой отсчета для этих методов служит левый верхний угол экрана.

Для Google Chrome есть специальный флаг `--window-position=x,y`, с помощью которого можно открыть браузер сразу с заданными координатами.

Пример:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.set_window_size(400, 300)
print(driver.get_window_position())
driver.set_window_position(900,10)
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver1.get("http://www.google.com")
driver1.set_window_size(400, 300)
driver1.set_window_position(10,10)
```